# Demonstration of setState?

Tags: reactjs

Can someone demonstrate how setState is asynchronous like showing the problem and how/why?

this is the code i tried

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
    };
    this.mengUbah = this.mengUbah.bind(this);
  }

  mengUbah(){
    this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1});

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.mengUbah}>CLICK HERE</button>
      <h1>{this.state.counter}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

but i think those code works perfectly so i can't tell the asynch problem.
I've tried to read all about setState but still can't understand

Comment: To demonstrate it you need to run `this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1});
` twice one call after another

Answer (score 0):

Guess the output of the following,

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      val: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({val: this.state.val + 1});
    console.log(this.state.val);    // first log

    this.setState({val: this.state.val + 1});
    console.log(this.state.val);    // second log

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({val: this.state.val + 1});
      console.log(this.state.val);  // third log

      this.setState({val: this.state.val + 1});
      console.log(this.state.val);  // fourth log
    }, 0);
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: expected result is 1 2 3 4 but showing 0 0 2 3 instead, so all setState method is not executed one by one and immediately but collects all setState and executed with one go when other process have been executed?

Comment: 1) setState actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains. This is explained in the documentation of setState.

setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Comment: When using setState in setTimeout, it becomes sync. I can't find a better explanation of the reason at this moment. Refer to https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12312